# What are the best VoIP providers?

Tags: voip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommendations for cheap and reliable VoIP service?](https://superuser.com/questions/60177/recommendations-for-cheap-and-reliable-voip-service)

For the general customer, who are the best VoIP providers?

I would like to know who provides the most robust features.

Comment: Please add some more information on your exact VoIP requirements

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/60177/recommendations-for-cheap-and-reliable-voip-service

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your country. For example Skype cannot provide a number here in Canada. I am very happy with **[Vbuzzer](https://www.vbuzzer.com/index.php)** - $25 a year for the number and $25 a year to land and cell lines, local, extra 25/year for long distance.

Answer (score 0):

[Skype](http://www.skype.com/) and [Vonage](http://www.vonage.com/) are two great VoIP providers. Skype is generally free with premium options like a dial in number and ability to call landlines. Vonage is a full blown subscription service that gives you a phone number and unlimited calling features.